# Tensorflow - TypeError: int() argument must be a string

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

I have a problem while executing object detection on tensorflow. It was working but now it's not. You can find error blow..

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection_CONVERRTED.py", line 166, in <module>
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
  File "/home/just/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/just/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1093, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "/home/just/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

**You can also find the line which creates error:**

```
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
  (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
      [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
      feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      np.squeeze(boxes),
      np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
      np.squeeze(scores),
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
  cv2.imshow('object detection',cv2.resize(image_np,(800,600)))
```

Comment: Can you show how you are loading image to 'image_np'

Comment: ` while True:
      ret, image_np = cap.read()`

Comment: cap = cv2.VideoCapture("output.avi")

Answer (score 0):

This happens when streaming fails or ends.
i.e

```
ret, image_np = cap.read()
print(image_np is None)
```

> //check if this evaluates to True

You can exit from while loop when streaming fails by giving an extra condition

```
if ret == 0:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. It was because of video format. When I converted video format avi to mp4 it worked.

But now I have different problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection_tutorial_CONVERRTED.py", line 175, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('object detection',cv2.resize(image_np,(800,600)))
cv2.error: /tmp/build/80754af9/opencv_1512687413662/work/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:611: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

Do you have any idea about this error? Thank you for your interest.